# `ip route add` does not allow duplicate entries, can I depend on that?

Tags: linux, routing, route, iproute

If I add a route with

`ip route add 172.10.1.0/24 via 10.0.0.100 dev eth0`

and then execute the same command a second time, it fails because the route is already present.

I don't see that behavior documented anywhere. Is it safe to depend on this behavior, or might different / future versions of Linux allow duplicate routes?

**use-case**

I'm writing a bash script that configures the routing table. I want to make it safe to run the script multiple times.

I see two options:

- Put the `ip route add` command within an `if` statement that runs `ip route list` and uses regex to check if the route is already in place.
- Just run `ip route add` and ignore if it fails because the route already exists.

The first doesn't seem very robust, as I have to depend on the output format of `ip route list`. The second seems to depend on undocumented behavior.

Comment: No. You can add multiple routes just now _if they have different metrics_: `for m in 1 2 3; do ip route add 172.10.1.0/24 via 10.0.0.100 dev eth0 metric $m; done`. A route with a metric != 0 is still a route. You don't have to use ip list | grep regex (yuck), you can check for the existence of a route explicitly: just replace the `add` with `list` in your command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ip route replace` instead of `add`.

This takes the same parameters as `add` but does not fail, when the route currently exists.

As `man ip-route` tells us

> ip route replace
>       change or add new one

it will silently add the route when it is not already set and "change"(replace) it with whatever you specify.

Comment: This is very nice! Thanks a lot. Too bad the same does not exist `ip rule`.